# Listen to a tap event in a jquery mobile listview

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, listview, jquery-mobile

I am building a HTML5 application with Intel XDK and Jquery Mobile. I've created a listview and want to listen to its 'tap' event. My code is very similar to the tutorial's, but something is still wrong. Maybe it's the place where I put it? I'm puting the event listener right after I refresh the listview. Documentation hasn't helped much and I couldn't find any question similar to mine :/
Code:

```
list.listview("refresh");
$('#favourslist > li').bind('tap', function(e)
{
    console.log('tapped');
    //var targetValue=this.getAttribute('title');
    //alert(targetValue);                                        
});
```

Comment: list.listview("refresh"); Are you sure this is the syntax to refresh??

Comment: `$(document).bind('tap', '#favourslist > li', function(e)` since `li` are dynamically injected into DOM/

Comment: @Omar thank you. Please submit your comment as an answer so it gets more visible to whoever visits this page. Also, if (just if) you could provide a link or a more complete explanation, it would be great. :)

Comment: I'm glad it works for you :) honestly, this question has been answer many times. http://stackoverflow.com/a/22280822/1771795 It's called _event delegation_.